# React/Typescript - which type to use for router props and how to get query value from it

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a route that looks like this:

```
  <AppRoute
    path="/auth/token"
    exact
    layout={AuthLayout}
    component={Auth}
    titleKey="root"
  />
```

AppRoute looks like this:

```
<Route
  {...rest}
  render={(props) => <Component props=props/>
/>
```

I see there that the props are of type `RouteComponentProps`, so I was using the same in the `Auth` component:

```
const Auth = (props: RouteComponentProps) => { }
```

I wonder how can I get the values from the query params if they exist, because sometimes I might have `redirect_to` query param added to the path like this:

```
/auth/token?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Ftechnology.com%2Fagent%2Fdashboard
```

How can I get that value from the props then. I only see that I can get it with `props.location.search` but that gives me the whole string after question mark with all the params. I would have to parse then myself the value from the param that I need. How can I get the value without having to parse it myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the query params you have to use this syntax:

```
const { search } = useLocation();

useEffect(() => {
    const params = new URLSearchParams(search);
    const queryValue = params.get('nameOfYourQueryParam');
}, [search])
```

Using a class based component the syntax is the same using `URLSearchParams` inside `componentDidUpdate` and/or `componentDidMount`, it depends on what you need.

Comment: Thank you Zhulien for the formatting, I'm kind of new to this :)

Comment: I got null when I use it like that ```const redirect = params.get('redirect_to');```

Comment: I've made a sandbox, here's the link. Hope it helps
[link](https://codesandbox.io/s/green-dust-1l42t?file=/src/App.js)